# Backbone callback functions, success not triggering code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js, callback, mouseevent

I'm doing a simple AJAX call to append an album's tracks in an unordered list.  It will append the tracks on the second click with this code:

```
window.app.views.AlbumView = Backbone.View.extend({...

      events: {
        'click .queue-add' : 'selectAlbum',
        'click .show-tracks' : 'showTracks',
        'click .hide-tracks' : 'hideTracks',
      },

      showTracks: function(){

        _this = this
        this.model.getTracks().forEach(function(track){
            _this.$el.find('.tracks').append("<li>"+track.attributes.title+"</li>");
        });
      },
```

Clearly the tracks hadn't been fetched in time for the first click so I added a callback function to the showTracks method like so:

```
  showTracks: function(){

    _this = this
    this.model.getTracks({
      success: function(tracks){
        console.log(tracks);
        tracks.forEach(function(track){
        _this.$el.find('.tracks').append("<li>"+track.attributes.title+"</li>");
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

Yet it won't enter the block and the console.log(tracks); puts nothing to the console.

Any tips would be really awesome here, thanks!!

```
app.models.Album = Backbone.Model.extend({

  ....

  getTracks: function() {
    this.tracks.fetch();
    return this.tracks
  },

  ....
});
```

Comment: What does `getTracks` look like?

Comment: Just added the following to the posting.  getTracks: function() {
    this.tracks.fetch();
    return this.tracks
  },

Comment: Why not `getTracks: function(opts) { this.tracks.fetch(opts); ...`? And `_this = this` creates a global variable, you probably want `var _this = this`.

Comment: good idea, this put me on the right track, had to put the success callback in the fetch, not in the get tracks

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find where did you invoke that callback. you may need modify "getTracks" method like this:

```
getTracks: function(callback) {
    this.tracks.fetch();
    callback(this.tracks); //you need to invoke the callback before return
    return this.tracks;
}
```

This is called "callback pattern", google it will find more.

and the backbone model's fetch method accept option argument, It is a object with two keys -- success and error -- both are function. If you provide this argument, backbone will call them automatically.

hope this help.